# QtWebKit - how to display a binary image from a database?

Tags: qt, qt4, sqlite, qtwebkit

I store images in binary format in SQLite database (client side) and use QtWebKit inside a desktop  application.

Everything works fine beside the need to display stored in the database binary images.

How to display a binary image from database in QtWebKit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way might be to implement your own URL scheme for these internal resources, e.g. mydb://foo.png - see [this article](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/32/qq32-webkit-protocols.html) for an overview of how this can be done.

Comment: Link is broken. [https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using%20a%20Custom%20Protocol%20with%20QtWebKit](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using%20a%20Custom%20Protocol%20with%20QtWebKit) - sample for PyQt. Thank you for the search direction

Answer (score 1):

If the images are not that big, you could also have a look at the `data` URL scheme. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394048/how-to-display-a-qimage-in-qwebkit/4398405#4398405) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new protocol a simple solution is given in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727080/how-to-get-qwebkit-to-display-image)

Basically extract the image and store on your disk. Then use **setHtml()** method of [QWebView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qwebview.html)
to set an html that points to your image.

Meaning the html must contain

```
<img src='your path on disk'>
```

tags.

This seems easier to me than implementing a protocol.

Comment: note, that this will work only if you add `page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls,true);
page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages,true);`, where page is QWebView's page()

Comment: This also means he must copy all of his images to a file system. That might be fine, but the OP may have some good reasons for keeping these in a DB.